# std::sync::mpsc::channel always in the same order

Tags: rust

No matter how many times I run the program, it always shows the numbers in the same order:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    for i in 0 ..10 {
        let tx = tx.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            tx.send(i).unwrap();
        }); 
    }

    for _ in 0..10 {
        println!("{}", rx.recv().unwrap());
    }
}
```

Code on the [playground](http://is.gd/R81g5B). The output is:

```
6
7
8
5
9
4
3
2
1
0
```

If I rebuild the project, the sequence will change. Is the sequence decided at compile time?

Comment: Note that the playground caches output, so if you run the same program twice without changing it, you'll get the same output. When I click on your playground link and run it, I get the same sequence as you. When I added a space to the end of the last line to force re-running, I got a slightly different sequence.

Answer (score 4):

What order would you expect them to be in? For what it's worth, on my machine I ran the same binary twice and got slightly different results.

Ultimately, this comes down to how your operating system decides to schedule threads. You create 10 new threads and then ask the OS to run each of them when convenient. A hypothetical thread scheduler might look like this:

```
for thread in threads {
    if thread.runnable() {
        thread.run_for_a_time_slice();
    }
}
```

Where `threads` stores the threads in the order they were created. It's unlikely that any OS would be this naïve, but it shows the idea.

In your case, every thread is ready to run immediately, and is very short so it can run all the way to completion before the time is up.

Additionally, there might be some fairness being applied to the lock that guards the channel. Perhaps it always lets the first of multiple competing threads submit a value. Unfortunately, the [implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.3.0/src/libstd/sync/mpsc/mod.rs) of channels is reasonably complex, so I can't immediately say if that's the case or not.